# How to access the key values in python dictionary with variables?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dict whose keys are numbers. It looks like this:

```
{'1': 3, '2': 7, '3', 14}
```

I need to access the value of each key with a variable, but get stuck because of the quotation marks of keys. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you show your code please?

Comment: The quotation marks mean they're strings.

Comment: We can help you better if we see your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Unfortunately it's a little hard to tell what you're asking. Could you provide what you've tried so far, what the error is, and the result you want?

Comment: typo: `{'1': 3, '2': 7, '3': 14}`

Comment: Sorry it's my first question and I didn't know posting the code was important. But I tried to convert them into string based on @TigerhawkT3 's comment and it's solved. Thanks all for your nice help.

Answer (score 2):

You can cast your number to a string,

```
my_dict = {'1': 3, '2': 7, '3': 14}

number = 2
print(my_dict[str(number)])
```