# How to access the key values in a nested python dictionary with variables?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am cleaning up some ROS robot code using the method in [this QA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39340225/how-to-access-the-key-values-in-python-dictionary-with-variables). This is not ROS related.

Here is the original code:

```
 data = []
 data.append(sensor[thermo].data.thermo)
 data.append(sensor[imu].data.imu.x)
 data.append(sensor[imu].data.imu.rotation.x)
```

Now I have a list of tuples containing all the topics so I can loop around:

```
topics = [('thermo', 'thermo'),
          ('imu', 'imu.x')
          ('imu', 'imu.rotation.x')]
```

and:

```
for sensor, topic in topics:
    data.append(getattr[sensor].data, topic)
```

This works for `thermo`, but not for `imu`, and I am getting the following error:

> AttributeError: 'imu' object has no attribute 'x'

How can I fix the `getattr` statement to achieve the goal here?

Comment: If the depth is fixed, you can combine `getattr` : `...getattr(getattr(sensor[thermo], "att1", None), "attr2", None)...`

Comment: Or you can use `reduce` from `functools`: `reduce(getattr, "att1.att2.att3".split('.'), sensor[imu])` I think the question is duplicated : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279082/python-chain-getattr-as-a-string

Comment: @machine424 If you think this question is a duplicate of another post, flag it as such. Also, OP, your Q&A link is broken, so you should update it to the correct URL.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python Chain getattr as a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3279082/python-chain-getattr-as-a-string)

Comment: @Bogdan Did you try `.imu.linear.x` instead of `.imu.x`?

Comment: @BenyaminJafari This is not a ROS related issue. The sensor data path is what it is here.

Comment: @machine424, I did not know there is a function that handles this. This can be considered as duplicate but I think it is a good example on `reduce` function's application example here and useful to others when they search for this solution. Would you put it in the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `reduce` of `functools` can be used:

```
reduce(getattr, "att1.att2.att3".split('.'), sensor[imu])
```